# GPS onLocationChanged location does not update after standing still for a few seconds

Tags: android, locationlistener

**Issue:**
onLocationChanged location **sometimes** doesn't update after standing still for a few seconds.
**Description**: After the `listener` starts to work, and I move the device, location gets updated. Then I stand still and don't move. After that, I keep moving. What it logs doesn't change and it keeps logging the same location. 
**Phone and Android version:** Samsung S6, Android 6.0.1

The example log: (before standing still)

```
onLocationChanged: new location (60.98367243212177, 25.638220444285892)
onLocationChanged: new location (60.98367227235308, 25.638231264557437)
onLocationChanged: new location (60.98367068663074, 25.638241549966416)
```

(after standing still)

```
onLocationChanged: new location (60.983707386852174, 25.63813532475042)
onLocationChanged: new location (60.983707386852174, 25.63813532475042)
onLocationChanged: new location (60.983707386852174, 25.63813532475042)
onLocationChanged: new location (60.983707386852174, 25.63813532475042)
```

My function to start the listener:

```
 public void startLocationListener(){
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    MyLocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
    if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1,0,locationListener);
    }
```

LocationListener class:

```
private final class MyLocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged: new location (" + location.getLatitude() +", " +  location.getLongitude()+")");
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: ");
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: ");
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider + " status " + status+ "extra " + extras.toString());
    }
}
```

This does not happen all the time, I think it might have something to do with the satellite or the phone. Does someone have any idea about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: GPS is known to not be a source of 100% accurate information all the time. Why does it surprise you that the location doesn't change if you stand still..?

Comment: @TimCastelijns The problem is after I stand still, and try to move again, the onChangedLocation is caled but it doesn't update the location. On the other hand, I think the GPS is very sensitive that even I stand still, the location should change very little.